# How to logout a deleted user that is currently logged in, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, session, session-storage

I have a list of users that i can delete from once i log in with any of the users. I want to remove the currentAccount from sessionStorage if the currently logged in user deletes himself. I am using an id to delete a user. This is how i have defined it so far.

```
function deleteUser(id) {
      let form = document.querySelector("#queryForm");
      let formData = new FormData(form);
      formData.append("action", DELETE);
      formData.append("ids", id);
      sendPost("/SMS/user", formData2Url(formData), handleDelete);
      let currentAccount = sessionStorage.getItem("currentAccount");
      if (id === currentAccount.id) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem(currentAccount);
      }
      console.log(id);
      console.log(currentAccount);
      console.log(Object.values(currentAccount[0]));
  }
```

Comment: Did you mean `.removeItem("currentAccount");`?

Comment: Not sure what you expect `Object.values(currentAccount)[0]` to log, given that `currentAccount` will be either `null` or a string

Comment: @Bergi actually, it should be ‘ Object.values(currentAccount)[0])’. What am actually trying to do is to get the id of the current and compare it with id of the deleted user. If the deleted user is the same as the user with the currentAcount, I want to remove the currentAccount from the sessionStorage.

Comment: Please show us the value you're storing in session storage. It looks like you forgot to parse it, a string has no `.id` property

Comment: This is how it shows in the console `{"id":1,"password":"111111","userName":"admin"}`

Comment: So use `JSON.parse`. Presumably that's what you used in other places where working with `currentAccount` in session storage?